# Why are my "other" flags always declined?

Tags: discussion

> [If you see anything in the system that is evil, weird, or in any way exceptional and deserving of moderator attention for any reason… flag it! That’s the primary job of a moderator: to look at every flagged post, and take action if necessary.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

So every time I see a situation that I can't (fully) deal with (i.e. ***requires more than a CV***), I flag it for moderator attention (of course in addition to spraying downvotes and VLQ/NAAs :D).

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23967412/2888561) is a dup of a bunch of other questions, can be found with "I'm feeling lucky" the question title, has poor grammar, shows no effort, shows no question, shows no problem, shows no attempted solution. It attracted 3 answers before closing (which took longer that usual since 3kers who *weren't* whores weren't on), pity-upvoting, meta-comments, and whores. The world would be a better place with it deleted, so I asked a mod to do that. "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" Wut?
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967873/is-there-a-simple-way-to-auto-scroll-the-below-jquery-slider) is the second repost (of crap) accompanied by rude comments from OP. I asked for a suspension or ban. "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" Wut?

I've complained before about specific cases. But generally, why are these all declined?

Oh, and if you think I'm not doing all I can, you're wrong.

[image: Review]

[image: Flags]

Comment: You have over 3k, have you considered just voting to close things that should be?

Comment: @Ben I gave reasons why that wasn't enough.

Comment: Dupe questions don't require moderator attention.  The system already provides tools for users to close a question as duplicate.  Why are you flagging for mod intervention in these cases?  Also, whores.

Comment: For the first question, it got closed within an hour. Hardly seems that moderator intervention was necessary. For the second, where is the post of which it is allegedly a duplicate?

Comment: @Will I was asking for a *suspension or ban*! Keeping track of deleted dups is hard since I can't view deleted posts.

Comment: If your first example is a dupe, why didn't you flag it as a dupe instead of "other". That seems to be clearly a waste of moderator time. If users ask enough questions that get closed as dupes, they will probably be auto banned.

Comment: @Andrew 1) As I said, closing isn't harsh enough. I want the question, answers, and comments banished from the system, rep revoked. There is a difference. 2) There are two of them which I don't have links for, look at OPs deleted questions.

Comment: The first case is definitely not a use case for an Other flag.  In your second flag, were you specific that the user reposted their question?  Did you provide a link to the previous?  Also, unless the comments were deleted, I didn't see anything rude there.  And definitely nothing requiring a suspension or ban, repost or not.

Comment: Also, while I want many questions nuked from orbit, OPs punished by severe beating, and points taken from them and placed on my account, there isn't much chance of this happening, so I'd fully expect any Other flags demanding these actions (even if we drop the last demand, so don't focus on that joke) seem very likely to be declined.

Comment: @Will The comments were deleted. I flagged them as rude/offensive. Lost the link (question deletion complicated it). Made it clear: "**Keeps reposting help-vamp crap question. Please suspend/ban.**"

Comment: Help vampires get shut out of the system automatically.  I don't think mods are going to respond to any request to directly suspend another user.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DhcFe.png

Comment: Your comments were aggressive and makes no sense. I have seen that question and it was perfect example of questions that we can refer how to ask.... If you found duplicate than cast close vote and move away thanks

Comment: @Null You seem optimistic! I guess you're ignoring the fact that the FAQ is linked to everywhere and new questioners have to scroll and click thru a shortened [how to ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Most questions are abandoned, let alone improved. For the second case: I was reporting the rude comments (one got -100'd) and negative attitude too.

Answer (score 13):

I can't speak for the moderators who declined them, but in my opinion neither of these are really particularly deserving of moderator attention. Solicited moderator attention is **expensive** there are a few moderators and community managers and they work really hard to go through a lot of flags.

From that same post:

> Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those (hopefully rare) **exceptional conditions that should not normally happen**, but when they do, they can bring your entire community to a screaming halt — if you don’t have human exception handling in place.

Sadly, such bad questions are posted in Stack Overflow all the time. While we have the ability to flag questions as very low quality - that option is reserved for extreme cases. The rule of thumb is to only flag things the community can't deal with itself.

More specifically:

- **Do not use flags to indicate a downright incorrect, wrong or unhelpful answers** - that's what voting is for. I got that one wrong a few times myself when I started flagging.
- **Do not use flags to indicate a poor or duplicate question** we have close votes and duplicate votes for that. This is especially for the one vote close of questions by gold badge holders, for example - you're always welcome to the JS chat room for JS, the PHP chat room for PHP and the Python chat room for Python to ask a regular for a binding dupe vote for example.

That said.

**Do flag questions you don't think the community can handle itself** or handle itself quick enough.

Flag racism, bigotry, porn, viruses, and anything that you think requires *immediate* attention. A common case for this is someone forgetting their database password in the question, which requires a revision wipe users can't do.

Moderators will simply decline flags they don't deem exceptional. That doesn't mean your help isn't appreciated, it's their way to guide you. I wouldn't take it the wrong way.

#### As for the particular questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967412/add-and-remove-class-to-span-using-jquery - I'd close vote and down vote that question, and leave a comment for OP about improving **quality**. I would not personally delete vote it since I think OP can salvage it. Remember that old questions with a negative score and no upvoted answers get automatically deleted :)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967873/ - your comment there is aggressive in my opinion. A close vote and a delete vote would also be a good choice here in my opinion, perhaps even just a close vote so OP can improve it.

Comment: "While we have the ability to flag questions as very low quality" I flagged 20 questions VLQ. Only 2 questions qualified (in my mind) for "other". This was a *really* bad day. I don't usually request that. Isn't that exceptional?

Comment: "Do not use flags to indicate a poor or duplicate question" I was indicating a poor *user*.

Comment: "I think OP can salvage it" BWAHAHAHAHA! Wait, you're serious? Let me laugh even harder! BWAHAHAHAHAHAH! No. OP is crap. Question is crap. Answers are crap. Comments are crap. The world would be a better place if OP and all answerers got banned. And question deleted. Which is why I flagged. "Remember that old questions with a negative score and no upvoted answers get automatically deleted :)" Except some more idiots went and upvoted them all. And got one accepted.

Comment: This sort of comment is why we can't have nice things :(

Comment: The problem with the second question is that it was posted **3** times. I don't give a dam about quality, that's when the OP needs to be nuked.

Comment: Well, is it *not right*?

Comment: There are systems in place to automatically ban repeat offenders, question bans for instance.

Comment: How can you question-ban somebody with so much rep?

Comment: Anyone's capable of having a history of terrible questions (yes, even a high-rep user), so it shouldn't matter to the question-ban algorithm how much rep someone has.

Answer (score 12):

I declined both of those flags. Neither of them were things that required immediate moderator intervention.

For [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967412/add-and-remove-class-to-span-using-jquery), your exact flag was

> Crap question, crap answers, off topic comments. Delete.

The question was asked 12 hours ago, and has already been placed on hold. Part of the reason for the new "on hold" wording (which eventually changes to "closed" after a certain duration) is to indicate that we want people to have a chance to improve their question. They have no such chance if we delete such questions immediately.

We have been instructed to only delete questions less than two days old if they are completely off topic, spam, trolling, or otherwise unsalvageable. This was a programming question that received an answer that someone put effort into, so it didn't fit any categories for immediate deletion. There was no need for me to step in there, so I declined that flag in order to indicate as much and let you know that there's no need to flag these.

Your second flag came on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967873/is-there-a-simple-way-to-auto-scroll-the-below-jquery-slider), where your wording was:

> Keeps reposting help-vamp crap question. Please suspend/ban.

No, I'm not going to suspend or ban a user who has given 528 answers, participated well on the site, and asked decent questions, all because you didn't like a question they asked. In fact, it looks like the reason they re-posted this question is because you downvoted their attempts at posting it, and you left comments that could be construed as hostile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967784/making-a-content-slider-auto-scroll) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967625/how-to-add-auto-scroll-to-the-below-jquery-content-slider). I know what you were going for with those comments, but there might have been better ways to word them.

At worst, this looked like a misunderstanding of how to improve an unclear question, which by no means is worth suspending someone over.

Comment: Hostile? Reposting your question aid unacceptable, especially for high-reps.

Comment: In any case, me not understanding flags is a serious problem. It means we need better education.

Comment: @bjb568 - What I wrote was "could be construed as hostile". Imagine yourself on the other side of a comment like "You see the edit button? Push it." or "I want a minimal reproducible example, examples of what you have tried and researched yourself, why those attempts failed, and what you think the problem might be. See how to ask." Those are fairly blunt statements, and I can understand how someone might not respond positively to them. Again, I know what you were trying to say, but I'm willing to go the extra mile for a user who has otherwise been a good participant in the site for a while.

Comment: In the case of declined flags, we decline as a means of educating users what items do and do not need our attention. In this case, I hope I've made clear why I did not feel these were actionable. BoltClock and I were talking about putting together a cheat sheet for what we look for in the various flag types, so maybe it's time we finished that and posted it as a proposed FAQ entry.

Comment: Well, I was thinking that the flag dialog should have basic guidelines, plus a link to an FAQ. And get rid of the misleading "flag everything" statement in the blog.

Comment: @BradLarson Those comments are not even half of it, [check out the deleted comments here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072848/how-do-you-center-multiple-divs/23072937). bjb those flags are extremely hostile :(